# setOnPreferenceChangeListener issues

Tags: android

**Issue1:**
 whenever after I call a `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` to a referenced key in `onCreate`, the preference summary updates but when I go back to the previous activity(home) and back again to this activity,the summary is destroyed along side the option to be stored for the value previously selected (like the activity is recreated)

**Issue2:**
I set a `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` to an `EditTextPreference` which should update its preference summary whenever a new value is added and set the preference summary to a defined text if such a value is 0. The issue is whenever I put that method in onCreate the app force closes.
Also here,the new value is not stored as the preference summary when  I try removing the method in onCreate.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainSettingsActivity 
  extends SherlockPreferenceActivity implements
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, Constants {


private static CheckBoxPreference query_checkbox;
private static EditTextPreference http_Headers;
private static CheckBoxPreference iPROXY;
private static ListPreference connection_Modes;
private static CheckBoxPreference globalization1;
private static ListPreference iMethod;
private static EditTextPreference localportEditTextPreference;
private static EditTextPreference httpPortEditTextPreference;
private static ProgressDialog progress;
private static boolean isRooted = false;
private boolean exited = false;
private final Handler mIncomingHandler = null;
private static SharedPreferences mPreferences = null;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);


    //Animation to handle (slide in/out)
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left , android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    //Add the preferences
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    //Set actionbar background when setting activity is called
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_background));

    //UP
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    localportEditTextPreference = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("local_port");
    httpPortEditTextPreference = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("http_proxy_port");
    connection_Modes = (ListPreference)findPreference("connection_modes");
    iMethod = (ListPreference)findPreference("injection_method");
    iPROXY = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("iProxy");
    globalization1 = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("globalization");
    http_Headers = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("http_headers");
    query_checkbox = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("parent_query_checkbox");
    connection_Modes.setSummary(getText(R.string.connection_using).toString() + " " + connection_Modes.getEntry());
    connection_Modes.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {

            preference.setSummary(MainSettingsActivity.this.getText(R.string.connection_using).toString() + " " + GMUtils.toUC(newValue.toString()));

            if(connection_Modes.getEntry().toString().compareToIgnoreCase("http") !=0){
                http_Headers.setEnabled(false);
                http_Headers.setSummary(R.string.http_summary);
                query_checkbox.setEnabled(false);
                query_checkbox.setSummary(R.string.http_summary);
            }

            if(newValue.toString().compareToIgnoreCase("http") == 0){
                http_Headers.setEnabled(true);
                http_Headers.setSummary(R.string.pref_http_headers_summary);
                query_checkbox.setEnabled(true);
                query_checkbox.setSummary(R.string.pref_query_summary);
                iPROXY.setEnabled(false);
                iPROXY.setSummary(R.string.option_not_available);
            }

            if(newValue.toString().compareToIgnoreCase("http") !=0){
                http_Headers.setEnabled(false);
                http_Headers.setSummary(R.string.http_summary);
                query_checkbox.setEnabled(false);
                query_checkbox.setSummary(R.string.http_summary);
            }

            return true;
        }

    });

    SetPortSummary(localportEditTextPreference, getText(R.string.pref_local_port_summary).toString(), getText(R.string.setport).toString());
    localportEditTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if ((newValue.toString().length() == 0) || (Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) > 65535) || (Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) < 0)){
                return false;
                }
                if (newValue.toString().contentEquals("0")) {
                  preference.setSummary(R.string.setport);
                }

                preference.setSummary(MainSettingsActivity.this.getText(R.string.pref_local_port_summary).toString() + " " + newValue.toString());

                return true;
        }
    });

    SetPortSummary(localportEditTextPreference, getText(R.string.pref_local_port_summary).toString(), getText(R.string.setport).toString());
    httpPortEditTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if ((newValue.toString().length() == 0) || (Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) > 65535) || (Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) < 0)){
                return false;
                }
                if (newValue.toString().contentEquals("0")) {
                  preference.setSummary(R.string.setport);
                }
                preference.setSummary(MainSettingsActivity.this.getText(R.string.pref_http_proxy_port_summary).toString() + " " + newValue.toString());
            return true;

        }
    });

}


public void SetPortSummary(EditTextPreference paramEditTextPreference, String paramString1, String paramString2){
    if ((paramEditTextPreference.getText().length() == 0) || (Integer.parseInt(paramEditTextPreference.getText()) > 65535) || (Integer.parseInt(paramEditTextPreference.getText()) < 0)) {
      paramEditTextPreference.setText("0");
    }
    if (paramEditTextPreference.getText().contentEquals("0"))
    {
      paramEditTextPreference.setSummary(paramString2);
      return;
    }
    paramEditTextPreference.setSummary(paramString1 + " " + paramEditTextPreference.getText());
  }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        finish();
        return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences paramSharedPreferences, String key) {

  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I found to the resolve of my problem in your question.

```
localportEditTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
       return success?true:false; // if not success false for go back
    }})
```